# ListView: How to display item selector when rows have clickable widgets?

Tags: android, android-listview

I've been struggling with this for quite some time now, although I am pretty sure this problem has been solved a thousand times over. I have looked at various other similar questions on SO and elsewhere but I haven't been able to solve this.

The core issue is:

> When I have clickable components in my list items, if I long-click on a row (for displaying the contextual action bar), the selector for the row does not appear. The long click is triggered though - there just isn't any visual feedback that the long click is happening.

Note that this problem is seen only when the row layout contains clickable items. Here is a quick sort of checklist of the things I've already tried:

- On the 'ListView', I've set `drawSelectorOnTop` to `true` (tried this both in XML as well as with `getListView()`
- On the 'ListView', I've set `choiceMode` to `singleChoice` (tried this both in XML as well as with `getListView()`
- On the 'ListView', I've set `listSelector` to various values - transparent, white etc. (tried this both in XML as well as with `getListView()`.
- Of course, the `LinearLayout` which hosts the individual rows in the list has `longClickable` set to `true`. Without this, the long clicks are not even registered.

No matter what I do, the long-press on the list item doesn't display any sort of selector although the long-press did happen and I do receive the `OnItemLongClick` callback.

Any clues on what could be causing this?

---

Code to reproduce the problem:

#### list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:baselineAligned="true"
android:longClickable="true"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnGo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:background="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on" />

</LinearLayout>
```

#### activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/configurations" >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

#### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

private ListView mListView;
private Context mContext;
private RowAdapter mAdapter;
private static final String LOG_TAG = "ListViewLongClick";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mContext = this;
    mListView = getListView();
    mListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    mListView.setSelector(android.R.color.white);
    mListView.setDrawSelectorOnTop(true);
    mAdapter = new RowAdapter(mContext, R.layout.list_item, R.id.tvTitle,
            getResources().getStringArray(R.array.configurations));
    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Long-click on item " + position,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
    });
}

static class RowAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private int mResource;
    private String[] configs;

    public RowAdapter(Context context, int resource,
            int textViewResourceId, String[] objects) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
        this.mResource = resource;
        this.configs = objects;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View viewToReturn = convertView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            viewToReturn = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    this.mResource, null, false);
        }

        TextView label = (TextView) viewToReturn.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        label.setText(configs[position]);
        Button btn = (Button) viewToReturn.findViewById(R.id.btnGo);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Aha! You clicked on the star button");
            }
        });
        return viewToReturn;
    }

}

}
```

#### strings.xml

```
<resources>

<string name="app_name">ListViewLongClick</string>
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
<string name="menu_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="title_activity_main">MainActivity</string>

 <string-array name="configurations">
    <item >Phone-Port</item>
    <item >Phone-Land</item>
    <item >Tab7-Port</item>
    <item >Tab7-Land</item>
    <item >Tab10-Port</item>
    <item >Tab10-Land</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

Comment: Give us your array too please =) I'm lazy

Comment: @CFlex Added. I'd thought not everyone is as lazy as I am. Turns out I was wrong :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change your list_items like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:baselineAligned="true"
              android:longClickable="true"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:background="@android:drawable/list_selector_background"
        >

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnGo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:background="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I added `android:background="@android:drawable/list_selector_background"` in your `LinearLayout`.

Hope this helps you =)

Comment: That did it! I owe you two days of debugging effort :-). BTW, what's the list_selector_background? I want to customize it because right now, the selector appears only when I am long-pressing the item. Once the selection is complete, it goes away. I want the selector background to appear as long as the user doesn't dismiss the current selection (or select an action on the CAB).

Comment: The selector can change the drawable depending on the state of the object. You can make drawables for state_pressed, state_focused, etc. There is a lot of tuts on Google about this. If you want to set a color after you lonClicked, I suggest you to add an attributes isSelected and change the backgroundColor of your linearLayout if isSelected==true/false. This is one way to do it, I don't say this is the best.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the hint. I'll look around.

Answer (score 0):

Make a ContextMenu in the res/menu folder and override the onCreateContextMenu method:

```
 @Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Please select:");
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
}
```

Override the onContextItemSelected method. And don't forget to add the following line in the onCreate method:

```
registerForContextMenu(getListView());
```

Refer to the following [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu) for more info.

Comment: Won't this show a floating menu (sort of a popup)? This is not what I want. I want to show a Contextual Action Bar (which is the very next section on the page you linked to).